# Could not resolve module / unresolved requirement org.eclipse.core.runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, java-11, target-platform

I have updated eclipse target plattform to eclipse version 2020_06 / JDK 11 (old version: Oxygen 4.7. and JDK 8). 'org.eclipse.core.runtime' is added as plugin depedency in the MANIFEST.MF of ch.myorg.myapp.ide.app. If I start the RCP application from the IDE I get following error. What could be the problem here? Where 'org.eclipse.core.runtime' is missing?

```
java.version=11.0.7
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product ch.myorg.myapp.ide.app.product
Command-line arguments:  -product ch.myorg.myapp.ide.app.product -data C:\projects\workspaces\myappWorkspace -dev file:C:/Projects/Workspaces/Eclipse2020-06-workspace_2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/myorg-ide.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY ch.myorg.myapp.ide.app 2 0
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: ch.myorg.myapp.ide.app [1]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: ch.myorg.common.util.logging; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: ch.myorg.common.util.logging.V2; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.18.0"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1420)
An error has occurred. See the log file
```

config.ini:

```
#Product Runtime Configuration File

osgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/ch.myorg.myapp.ide.app
eclipse.product=ch.myorg.myapp.ide.app.product
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start,org.eclipse.equinox.ds@start
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
org.eclipse.ui.workbench/SHOW_BUILDID_ON_STARTUP=true
usage_reporting_enabled=false
# Tell the BundleLoader to search the classes in the following packages in the system classloader first (before searching the bundles). 
org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=com.sun.*,sun.*
# osgi.hook.configurators=ch.myorg.myapp.ide.app.hooks.myappDevelopmentHookConfigurator
osgi.framework.extensions=ch.myorg.myapp.ide.app
```

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: Is there more to the log output?

Comment: No it's the same as above

Comment: Did you update the plug-ins list and start levels in the .product file to include the changes between the releases? If you are running using Run As Eclipse Application from within Eclipse you will also need to update the Run Configuration.

Comment: Yes in the .product file I pressed the button "Add Recomended…". org.eclipse.core.runtime is available here with start Level 'default' and Auto-Start 'true'. I also pressed "Add Required Plug-ins" in the "Plug-ins" tab of the "Run Configuration". If I press the "Validate Plug-ins" button no problems were detected. "org.eclipse.core.runtime" is also listed here in the target platform section with Auto-Start 'true' and Start-Level 'default'.

Comment: Possibly something to do with the use of `osgi.framework.extensions`. My guess is that is loaded before the other plug-ins are resolved.

Comment: How can I change the behaviour? I tried it like in the following post:

Answer (score 0):

I tried to uncomment `osgi.framework.extensions` and changed the start level of `org.eclipse.core.runtime` in config.ini like this:

```
#Product Runtime Configuration File

osgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/ch.myorg.myapp.ide.app
eclipse.product=ch.myorg.myapp.ide.app.product
# osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start,org.eclipse.equinox.ds@start
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@4:start
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
org.eclipse.ui.workbench/SHOW_BUILDID_ON_STARTUP=true
usage_reporting_enabled=false
# Tell the BundleLoader to search the classes in the following packages in the system classloader first (before searching the bundles). 
org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=com.sun.*,sun.*
# osgi.hook.configurators=ch.myorg.myapp.ide.app.hooks.myappDevelopmentHookConfigurator
# osgi.framework.extensions=ch.myorg.myapp.ide.app
```

I am getting now the following error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2020-07-15 14:27:11.405
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.runtime [3]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.10.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1838)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1781)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1743)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1665)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-07-15 14:27:11.409
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.18.0.v20200506-2143.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2020-07-15 14:27:11.414
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.runtime [3]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.10.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-07-15 14:27:11.436
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1420)
```